# responsive filemanager doesn't show pdf

Tags: responsive-filemanager

I'm using [responsivefilemanger](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com) for a filemanger. The thing is now, if i upload a pdf, it upload it onto the server, but it doesn't shows it on the filemanager itself. It seams there is a problem to generate thumbnails from pdf or other files (word, excel). With Images, all works very well.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

A bit late, but faced the same problem just now: If using as standalone dialog, be sure to set the url passing the right type parameter `dialog.php?type=2`.
From the official docs (http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/):

Select Image: (type=1 and set id of input text in field_id variable):
path to filemanager../filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&field_id=fieldID

Select Video: (type=3 and set id of input text in field_id variable): 
path to filemanager../filemanager/dialog.php?type=3&field_id=fieldID

Select File: (type=2 and set id of input text in field_id variable): 
path to filemanager../filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&field_id=fieldID